# Trigger keeps failing to compile. Claims table not found when table exists

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers, database-trigger

All the tables that are called definitely exist. I double checked the spelling as well. 
The errors sqldeveloper gives are not very helpful and I can't seem to figure out why this is failing. I am attempting to make a trigger which updates the top5restaurants table when a new review comes in. I have a procedure which parses the review and adds them to the rating table. The top5restaurant table maintains the restaurants with the 5 highest ratings.

```
drop view bestratings_rest;
create view bestratings_rest(rid, rate) as 
(select distinct rid, max(stars) from rating
group by rid);



drop table top5restaurants;
create table top5restaurants(rid int);

insert into top5restaurants rid
    select rid from
            (select rid, rate from bestratings_rest r
            order by r.rate asc)
        where rownum <=5;
drop view top5rest;

create view top5rest as  
select rid, best from(    
    select t.rid, best from top5restaurants t
    inner join (select distinct rid, max(stars) as best from rating
    group by rid) b
    on t.rid = b.rid);


create or replace trigger top5_trigger
    after insert on rating
    for each row
    declare
    minrow top5rest%rowtype;
    restrid restaurant.rid%type;
    restname restaurant.name%type;
    begin

    insert into minrow
    select rid, min(best) from top5rest;


    insert into restname
    select rid from restaurant
    where :new.rid = restaurant.rid;

    if :new.stars > minrow.best  then
    DELETE FROM top5restaurants
    where top5restaurants.rid = :new.rid;
    insert into top5restaurants values(rid);
    end if;

    end;
    /
--    
--
begin
update_reviews('Jade Court','Sarah M.', 4, '08/17/2017');

update_reviews('Shanghai Terrace','Cameron J.', 5, '08/17/2017');

update_reviews('Rangoli','Vivek T.',5,'09/17/2017');

update_reviews('Shanghai Inn','Audrey M.',2,'07/08/2017');

update_reviews('Cumin','Cameron J.', 2, '09/17/2017');

end;
/    
select * from top5restaurants;
```

sqldeveloper outputs:

View BESTRATINGS_REST dropped.

View BESTRATINGS_REST created.

Table TOP5RESTAURANTS dropped.

Table TOP5RESTAURANTS created.

5 rows inserted.

View TOP5REST dropped.

View TOP5REST created.

Trigger TOP5_TRIGGER compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR

---

7/5       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
7/17      PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
11/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
11/17     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
18/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
18/40     PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
Errors: check compiler log

Comment: minrow and restname are not tables, they are a rowtype and a columntype. You can't insert into them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't `insert into` a scalar variable.  You can do a `select into`.  The statement

```
select rid 
  into restname
  from restaurant
 where :new.rid = restaurant.rid;
```

is syntactically valid.  But it is almost certainly incorrect.  Presumably, you want to select the restaurant name not the rid

```
select name 
  into restname
  from restaurant
 where :new.rid = restaurant.rid;
```

If you declare a `%rowtype` variable, then you want to do a `select *` into that variable.  Otherwise you'll get a compilation error in the future if anyone adds or removes a column.  You'd have to add a predicate that specified which row you wanted to select.  My guess is that you want something like this to give the row with the lowest `best` score (or the row with the lowest `rid` if there are two with the same low score

```
 select *
  into minrow
  from top5rest low
 where not exists( select 1
                     from top5rest high
                    where low.best > high.best )
   and not exists( select 1
                     from top5rest same
                    where low.best = same.best
                      and low.rid > same.rid )
```

More fundamentally, though, even if you get your syntax errors corrected, you're going to get a runtime mutating table error if you try to query the `rating` table (which your view does) from inside a row-level trigger on the `rating` table.  That's not allowed.  It almost guarantees that you have a problem in your logic.  In this case, there seems to be no need for a separate table to store the top 5 restaurants.  Realistically, your view should just do that calculation if you need the results in real-time or you should create a materialized view that refreshes periodically if you don't need to see a restaurant's overall rating change instantly when new ratings are added.  So you probably don't want a trigger at all.

Comment: Yeah I realized these syntax errors afterward. This definitely is not needed Unfortunately, some hair-brained require me to use a trigger for this.